# How to implement login system in node.js and expressJs

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express, express-session

I am developing an app in node.js and using expressJs, but I am a **PHP** developer, I know that in **PHP** we can use `session` to implement login and I thought in node.js case is the same, so as I searched I found the `express-session` module, and I tried to implement this way.
This `app.js` file

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'app/views');
app.use(require('./routes/login_api'));
app.use(require('./routes/login'));
app.use(require('./routes/Index_api'));
app.use(require('./routes/index'));

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

So as you can see I have four different routes, `/routes/login` renders the login.ejs template, `/routes/login_api` handles the requests and response of the login page,
`/routes/Index_api`, `/routes/Index_api` (which is my dashboard), is the same way. This is `login_api

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'fmis'
});
conn.connect();

router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
router.post('/login_api', function(req, res) {
    var Username = req.body.Username;
    var Password = req.body.Password;
    var query = "SELECT `User_Id`, `User_Username`, `User_Password`, `User_Name`, `User_Last_Name`, `User_Type`,  `User_Photo`  FROM `users` WHERE `User_Deleted` = 0 AND `User_Username`='" + Username + "' AND  `User_Password` = '" + Password + "'";

    conn.query(query, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.end();
        } else {
            if (result.length == 1) {
                req.session.Username = result[0].User_Username;
                req.session.Password = result[0].User_Password;
                req.session.UserType = result[0].User_Type;

            }
        }
        console.log(req.session.Username); // gives the right result
    });
    console.log(req.session.Username); // gives the undefined 

});
```

As far as I know the `session.Username` is a global variable (as it is in PHP)
so it should be accessible in everywhere but when I access it in `routes/index` route it gives the undefined result, not even that if write the `console.log(req.session.Username);` inside query callback function it gives the right result which is returned from the database but when I place it out side query callback function it gives `undefined` result.
So any suggesstion please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the **async and non-blocking** nature of Node.js. When you call `conn.query` the process **does not block** and moves on to the next statement which is `console.log` (outside the callback). Most probably the callback hasn't been called yet. Callback will be called at an arbitrary time when either the `result` or `error` is available. That's why you see that "weird" behaviour. *The order of execution is not necessarily the order of statements*.

**A Quick Solution:**

I recommend [Passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport). It is popular and easy to use for handling authentication.

You can use it as a middleware which is cleaner and get access to the current user simply by `req.user` which is available in the request context. It has different authentication strategies, including OAuth, and easy to work with.

**NOTE**: It requires the session and cookie-parser.

In your particular application see:

- `LocalStrategy` to load user details from database;
- `de/serializeUser` for reading and writing user data from session;

Also you need to `use` `passport.initialize()` and `passport.session()` middlewares. See the project's page for details on how to use it.